# Foreign key error, 'base table or view already exists' laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

First of all, I have already looked for this error and have not been served the solutions. I have added to my user table the clinic_id foranea key of the clinical table but when doing the migration I get the following errror:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varc
  har(150) not null, `surnames` varchar(150) not null, `email` varchar(150) not null, `password` varchar(150) not null, `phone` int not null, `clinic_id` int not null, `remember_toke
  n` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists
```

> 2014_10_12_000000_create_clinics_table.php:

```
    public function up()
{

    Schema::create('clinics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('province');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

> 2014_10_12_000001_create_users_table.php:

```
  public function up()
{


    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('surnames');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('phone');
        $table->integer('clinic_id');
        $table->foreign('clinic_id')->references('id')->on('clinics');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I returned to the previous version of my project and I got that error did not come out again, now apparently it makes everything correct but still does not add the foreign field to the users of the table, I tried it like this:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('surnames');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('clinic_id');
        $table->foreign('clinic_id')->references('id')->on('clinics');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```

and like this;

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surnames');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('clinic_id');
        $table->foreign('clinic_id')->references('id')->on('clinics');
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add to the existing table, not create a new table. So you just need to list only the columns you're adding, and use `table` instead of `create`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('clinic_id');
        $table->foreign('clinic_id')->references('id')->on('clinics');
    });
}
```

Comment: I deleted the tables and I did again migrations and get the same error...

Comment: Do you have multiple migrations for the users table?

Comment: I have only one migrations to users... it's so rare

Comment: Try a `php artisan migrate:reset` if you don't mind losing all of your data, then check your database to make sure it's empty. If it's all empty, then do `grep users database/migrations | grep create` from the command line within your project folder. If there's only one, try migrating again.

Answer (score 0):

The message seems pretty clear, you are trying to create a table that already exists, try running:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

If that doesn't work It may be you rolled back but missed to drop the table, drop it mannually. If you tried to add a column you are doing it wrong, you need to call the existing table and attach the new columns.

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('clinic_id');
        ...
    });
```

EDIT:
If you used `php artisan make:auth` in order to create the auth system then you have already a `users` table migration, If you did, then, trying to create a new table named `users` is the issue because you used the following:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        });//This is just for creating a new users table
```

If you wanted to create new columns in the user table then you need to make the following migration:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    });// See the difference?, create/table
```

If you don't want to complicate yourself just delete the migration for the users models you just created and add the columns to the original `users` migration.

Comment: I deleted the tables and I did again migrations and get the same error...

Comment: Ok, I suppose you have two migrations with the users table, you can add the columns you need at the first migration and just delete the new one or keep the first migration and edit the new one in order to just add the new columns, Schema::create is for create a table and Schema::table is for retrieving an already created table and edit it as you like

Comment: I have only one migrations to users... it's so rare

Comment: Can you show me all your migrations?(Just the names,If you dont have too many)

Comment: You can edit your question with all your migration files

Comment: I returned to the previous version of my project and I got that error did not come out again, now apparently it makes everything correct but still does not add the foreign field to the users of the table,
 I  have edited my post with the new code!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `unsigned()` to `integer('clinic_id')`.

```php
    $table->integer('clinic_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('clinic_id')->references('id')->on('clinics');
```

Remove manually all tables and run `php artisan migrate` with changes above.